# Empty collections get converted to null in Apache CXF service (JAX-WS)

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws

I have a web service with the following API:

```
public ReturnType myServiceMethod(Collection<MyInputType> inputs);
```

If I invoke my method with a non-empty collection, everything works fine. If the method is invoked, however, with an empty collection, then the parameter becomes `null` on the server side. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: How does the wsdl and your cxf/wsdl2java config look?

Comment: I haven't touched those things, so they must look like the defaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384986/apache-cxf-web-services-problems and if it's not this might help http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In the case above, the parameter is a collection. In the linked question, the parameter is a single instance of a type and that type has a collection as a member variable. There are many examples online of how to solve the later, but not the former.

Comment: But I think that's exactly the problem. In order to avoid the empty collection being transformed into null, you have to use a wrapper. Did you check the second url?

Comment: Yes, I read that before posting the question. The issue is that I don't want to use a wrapper. Think about it: internally, CXF must be generating the XML / Java types, so theoretically it should be possible to handle this case. I would even be willing to patch CXF to handle this.